# How to change slider? Is there possibility to do it in that way?

Tags: slider

how can I do 5 photos instead of 3, how to change their size, how to do that they will be change automatically becouse now I have to press play to start?

html:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Unstyled Example
        $.monte('#example1');

        // Styled Buttons Example
        // (see the CSS in the above style block)
        $.monte('#example2', {auto:false});

        // Callback Example
        // Format and append the HTML:
        $('#example3 > img').each(function(){
            $(this)
                .wrap('<div style="position:relative"/>')
                .parent()
                .append('<div><p>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p></div>')
                .append('<img src="frame.png" alt="" class="frame"/>');
        });
        // Hide the text on all but the center slide:
        $('#example3 div div').css({opacity: 0}).eq(0).css({opacity: 0.8});
        // Using the callbacks to reveal and hide the text:
        $.monte('#example3', {
            auto:false,
            callbackIn: function () {
                $(this[0]).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 450);
            },
            callbackAway: function () {
                $(this[0]).find('div').animate({opacity: 0}, 450);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is link to the source where I found it [https://github.com/paizai/monte][1]

Comment: Have you made any effort of changing the code yourself?

Comment: I set auto on true, so I have 1 thing, I tried to change size in css where I have height for example but nothing changed, it was in that line "#example1 .montePlay { width:41px; height:40px; background-position:-29px -120px; bottom:-20px; left:405px; }", I have no idea how to have more photos.